# PageObject Gem - Alert popup not being handled

Tags: alert, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I am new to PageObject (and ruby)...

I am having issues handling the Alert popup when user ID is not provided.

Here is the code and scenario:

When I click 'sign in' button without user ID then I am expecting an alert with a message, which I am verifying in my script.

***currently I get an error:***
`NoMethodError: undefined method`alert' for nil:NilClass`

***cucumber Then statement:***
Then I should see an popup message 'enter card number'

***step definition:***
`

```
Then(/^I should see an popup message "([^"]*)"$/) do |popup_msg|
  on(LoginPage).alert_msg
end

***Page object code:***
class LoginPage
  require_relative 'common'

  include PageObject
  include Common

  text_field(:collector, :id => 'j_col')
  text_field(:password, :id => 'j_password1')
  button(:sign_in, :value => 'Sign in')


  def login_to_nectar (collector = FigNewton.collector.colid, password = FigNewton.collector.password)
   self.collector = collector
   self.password = password
   sign_in
  end

  span(:pwd_error_msg, :css => 'p.error-message')


  def alert_msg
    message = @curr_page.alert do
      sign_in.click
    end
    message.should == 'enter card numbe'
    @alert_msg
  end

end
```

`

***....LATEST INFO....progress***

@Johnson thanks...now I am getting the error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError: Modal dialog present: "enter card number. "
```

I can see that PageObject is handling the popup. My new code below:

```
def alert_msg
    alert do
      self.sign_in.click
    end
    @alert_msg
end
```

I call this in step definition in the step before verifying the message as so....

```
When(***without a card number$/) do
  on(HomePage).click_login
  on(LoginPage).login_to_nectar('', FigNewton.collector.password)
  @current_page.**alert_msg**
end

Then***
  on(LoginPage).**alert_msg**.should == popup_msg
end
```

Comment: Johnson thanks for pointing me in the right direction...however now I am getting the following error:

Comment: Is the question answered now? I'm unclear as to what the status is.

Comment: Yes it is...After the initial changes I made and was getting the modal related error. I realized in my page class my login_to_nectar method was calling 'sign_in' element, so in effect this was being called twice (2nd time in alert_msg method). I took it out of 'login_to_nectar method and all worked.

Comment: If none of the other answers below fit, maybe put what you just said in an answer and accept it. This helps others who come along and view your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the initial changes I made and was getting the modal related error. I realized in my page class my login_to_nectar method was calling 'sign_in' element, so in effect this was being called twice (2nd time in alert_msg method). I took it out of 'login_to_nectar method and all worked. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Error message `NoMethodError: undefined method 'alert' for nil:NilClass` means that your `@curr_page` is nil, and thus does not have a defined method of #alert. Take a look at where you're defining this instance variable. It is the culprit.